# Convert Column of List to Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of lists in a spark dataframe.

```python
+-----------------+
|features         |
+-----------------+
|[0,45,63,0,0,0,0]|
|[0,0,0,85,0,69,0]|
|[0,89,56,0,0,0,0]|
+-----------------+
```

How do I convert that to a spark dataframe where each element in the list is a column in the dataframe? We can assume that the lists will be the same size.

For Example,

```python
+--------------------+
|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|
+--------------------+
|0 |45|63|0 |0 |0 |0 |
|0 |0 |0 |85|0 |69|0 |
|0 |89|56|0 |0 |0 |0 |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)?

Comment: what's datatype of features column. can you post your schema please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is actually the invert of the [`VectorAssembler`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) operation.

You can do it by converting to an intermediate RDD, as follows:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

# your data:
df.show(truncate=False)
# +-----------------+ 
# |        features | 
# +-----------------+
# |[0,45,63,0,0,0,0]|
# |[0,0,0,85,0,69,0]|
# |[0,89,56,0,0,0,0]|
# +-----------------+ 

dimensionality = 7
out = df.rdd.map(lambda x: [float(x[0][i]) for i in range(dimensionality)]).toDF(schema=['c'+str(i+1) for i in range(dimensionality)])
out.show()
# +---+----+----+----+---+----+---+ 
# | c1|  c2|  c3|  c4| c5|  c6| c7|
# +---+----+----+----+---+----+---+ 
# |0.0|45.0|63.0| 0.0|0.0| 0.0|0.0|
# |0.0| 0.0| 0.0|85.0|0.0|69.0|0.0| 
# |0.0|89.0|56.0| 0.0|0.0| 0.0|0.0| 
# +---+----+----+----+---+----+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getItem`:

```python
df.withColumn("c1", df["features"].getItem(0))\
  .withColumn("c2", df["features"].getItem(1))\
  .withColumn("c3", df["features"].getItem(2))\
  .withColumn("c4", df["features"].getItem(3))\
  .withColumn("c5", df["features"].getItem(4))\
  .withColumn("c6", df["features"].getItem(5))\
  .withColumn("c7", df["features"].getItem(6))\
  .drop('features').show()

+--------------------+
|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|
+--------------------+
|0 |45|63|0 |0 |0 |0 |
|0 |0 |0 |85|0 |69|0 |
|0 |89|56|0 |0 |0 |0 |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative without converting to rdd,

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

##Not incase of vectorAssembeler.
stop = df.select(F.max(F.size('features')).alias('size')).first().size ## if having a list of varying size, this might be useful.

udf1 = F.udf(lambda x : x.toArray().tolist(),ArrayType(FloatType()))
df = df.withColumn('features1',udf1('features'))

df.select(*[df.features1[i].alias('col_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,stop)]).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   45|   63|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|    0|    0|   85|    0|   69|    0|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: The question specifies column of 'list'. Why use toArray() here?

Comment: If it column of list, it fine,we don't need udf itself. but, the column name "features" is where it hits me.

Comment: @mayankagrawal OK guys, since each of our solution has its merit given the info (not) given, I suggest upvoting all to all (including Justin); in any case, OP is notorious for *not* accepting or upvoting good & arguably helpful answers. I proceed first...

Comment: @desertnaut i agree

Comment: @desertnaut Iagree too.

Comment: Good. As a bonus, I added code highlighting to your posts... ;) @mayankagrawal

Answer (score 2):

@desertnaut's answer can also be accomplished with dataframe and udf.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dimensionality = 7
column_names = ['c'+str(i+1) for i in range(dimensionality)]
splits = [F.udf(lambda val:val[i],FloatType()) for i in range(dimensionality)]
df = df.select(*[s('features').alias(j) for s,j in zip(splits,column_names)])
```

Comment: Did this work on column of vectors or column of array types ?

Comment: @Suresh nice catch - it won't work on column of vectors (tested)

Comment: Exactly, if we use array type, we can index it straightforward.

Comment: Although not sure, in udf,changing 'val' to 'val.values' might work for vectors.

Comment: @mayankagrawal does not

Comment: @mayankagrawal class vector has toArray() method . Only class densevector and sparsevector have values.Correct me if I am wrong. Please check this, http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector

Comment: @Suresh yes you are right. Did not know that. .toArray() will work in all cases of vector class.