# Convert Column of List to a Dataframe Column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of lists in a spark dataframe.

```
+-----+----------+
|c1   |  c2      |
+-----+----------+
|a |[1, 0, 1, 1] |
|b |[0, 1, 1, 0] |
|c |[1, 1, 0, 0] |
+-----+----------+
```

How do I convert this into another spark dataframe **where each list is turned into a dataframe column**? Also each entry from column 'c1' is the name of the new column created. Something like below.

```
+--------+
|a| b | c| 
+--------+
|1 |0| 1 |
|0 |0| 1 |
|1 |1| 0 |
|1 |0| 0 |
+--------+
```

***Note:*** I did think about following this: [Convert Column of List to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711657/convert-column-of-list-to-dataframe) and then taking a transpose of the resultant matrix. But, this creates quite a lot of columns [as the size of the list data I have is pretty huge] and therefore isn't an efficient solution.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: same length for each array ?

Comment: @Steven Yes I have used padding to ensure each array is of the same length. The only issue is, the length of each array might easily go into thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#Not a part of the solution, only used to generate the data sample
df = spark.sql("select stack(3 ,'a',array(1, 0, 1, 1), 'b',array(0, 1, 1, 0) ,'c',array(1, 1, 0, 0)) as (c1,c2)")

df.groupBy().pivot('c1').agg(F.first('c2')).selectExpr('inline(arrays_zip(*))').show()
```

---

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  1|
|  0|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+
```

---

This can be easily tested for large datasets

```
df = sql("select id as c1, transform(sequence(1,10000), e -> tinyint(round(rand()))) as c2 from range(10000)")
```

Just completed a succesfull execution of 10K arrays, 10K elements each, on a VM with 4 cores & 32 GB RAM (Azure Databricks).
Took 5.35 minutes.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking out for.
I do have a question around this though. Does the solution change if the size of the arrays / lists are different?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I am working with close 1.1M rows. The code provided by you does the job [and I do suspect it is a time consuming job]. But, right before the job starts I see the following Warning: ***WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.***. The job takes close to 569 sec to complete. Is this warning to be expected? @DavidדודוMarkovitz

Comment: Expected, since we are using `groupBy()`, which mean all rows goes to the same group. There are ways to split the load but it require more cumbersome code. If it works, leave it as is.

Comment: Yes, it does work and yes, I did suspect that the groupBy() call here would be the culprit. I wanted to confirm if this time frame in within the expected range. Thank you for taking your time to answer.