# How to remove 'duplicate' rows from joining the same pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to show a dataframe made by three columns. Two of them show the names of someone who worked in a common movie (indicated by code on the third code)

here's my code for the query:

```
name_data_df3 = movie_join_oscar_join_name.filter('Nazione in ("USA", "England", "France", "Canada", "Italy", "Austria")').select('knownForTitle','person').distinct()
art_pre_edge_data1 = name_data_df3.select(col('person').alias('artist1'), 'knownForTitle', )
art_pre_edge_data2 = art_pre_edge_data1.select(col('artista').alias('artist2'), col('knownForTitle').alias('knownForTitle2'))
art_edge_data = art_pre_edge_data1.join(art_pre_edge_data2, (art_pre_edge_data1.knownForTitle==art_pre_edge_data2.knownForTitle2) & (art_pre_edge_data1.artista!=art_pre_edge_data2.artista2))
art_edge_data = art_edge_data.drop(art_pre_edge_data2.knownForTitle2)
art_edge_data.select('*').show()
```

and here is the result:

```
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|          artist1|knownForTitle|         artist2|
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|   Robert Redford|    tt0070735|  George Roy Hill|
|  George Roy Hill|    tt0070735|   Robert Redford|
| Lionel Barrymore|    tt0022958|    Wallace Beery|
| Lionel Barrymore|    tt0022958|    Joan Crawford|
|    Wallace Beery|    tt0022958| Lionel Barrymore|
|    Wallace Beery|    tt0022958|    Joan Crawford|
|    Joan Crawford|    tt0022958| Lionel Barrymore|
|    Joan Crawford|    tt0022958|    Wallace Beery|
```

how can I remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using DataFrame functions. Compare the two columns alphabetically and assign values such that `artist1` will always sort lexicographically before `artist2`. Then select the distinct rows.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select(
    'knownForTitle',
    f.when(f.col('artist1') < f.col('artist2'), f.col('artist1')).otherwise(f.col('artist2')).alias('artist1'),
    f.when(f.col('artist1') < f.col('artist2'), f.col('artist2')).otherwise(f.col('artist1')).alias('artist2'),
).distinct().show()
#+-------------+----------------+----------------+
#|knownForTitle|         artist1|         artist2|
#+-------------+----------------+----------------+
#|    tt0070735| George Roy Hill|  Robert Redford|
#|    tt0022958|   Joan Crawford|Lionel Barrymore|
#|    tt0022958|   Joan Crawford|   Wallace Beery|
#|    tt0022958|Lionel Barrymore|   Wallace Beery|
#+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udf and do something like this

```
func_udf = f.udf(lambda x,y: sorted([x,y]), t.ArrayType(t.StringType()))

df2 = df.withColumn('artists', func_udf('artist1','artist2')).select(['artists',
                             'KnownForTitle']).distinct().show()
```

Comment: If you want to split that list back into columns, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark).