# How do I batch rename columns in pyspark efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to batch rename my columns in PySpark from:

```
 'collect_list(Target_Met_1)[1]' --> 'AB11'
 'collect_list(Target_Met_1)[2]' --> 'AB12'
 'collect_list(Target_Met_2)[1]' --> 'AB21'
 'collect_list(Target_Met_1)[150]' --> 'AB150'
```

How do I go about it in a programmatically? Right now, I can manually change the names using:

```
df.withColumnRenamed('collect_list(Target_Met_1)[1]', 'AB11')
```

But if I have 500 columns, it's not efficient. I realize that an other way to renaming it would be using something like a udf, but I cannot figure the best possible approach.

I have split the columns and that's not the problem. The problem is around renaming the column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split large array columns into multiple columns - Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648313/split-large-array-columns-into-multiple-columns-pyspark)

Comment: This is not about splitting the column, but more around renaming the problem.

Comment: You can rename like this. Just chain the renamings with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Figured out. Essentially I had to use a list comprehension to rename the columns. I was splitting columns mentioned in the link above. Here is what that did the trick:

```
df = df.select('1', '2', '3', *[df[col][i].alias("AB" + str(i + 1) + col) for col in columns for i in range(max_dict[col])])
```

Answer (score 1):

To rename all columns you can use the method `toDf`:

```
import re

df.toDF(*['AB' + ''.join(re.findall('\d+', i)) for i in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help too. It's a rename function similar to the Pandas rename functionality.

```
def rename_cols(map_dict):
  """
  Rename a bunch of columns in a data frame
  :param map_dict: Dictionary of old column names to new column names
  :return: Function for use in transform
  """
  def _rename_cols(df):
    for old, new in map_dict.items():
      df = df.withColumnRenamed(old, new)
    return df
  return _rename_cols
```

And you can use it like

```
spark_df.transform(rename_cols(dict(old1='new1', old2='new2', old3='new3')))
```