# How to create columns from list values in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like this:

```
Subscription_id Subscription parameters
5516            ["'catchupNotificationsEnabled': True","'newsNotificationsEnabled': True","'autoDownloadsEnabled': False"]
```

I need the output Dataframe to be as:

```
Subscription_id catchupNotificationsEnabled newsNotificationsEnabled    autoDownloadsEnabled
5516    True    True    False
```

How Can I achieve this in Pyspark? I have tried several options using UDF but couldn't succeed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the keys ahead of time?

Comment: @pault Yes, there are only these 3 parameters catchupNotificationsEnabled, newsNotificationsEnabled  and autoDownloadsEnabled with different values of True and False for different records

Comment: Could you provide the schema of the DataFrame ? Is "Subscription parameters" of type : StructType() or ArrayType() ? (or other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your "Subscription parameters" column is ArrayType().

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# Call SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc = sparkContext
```

First create the DataFrame

```
df = sc.createDataFrame([Row(Subscription_id=5516,
                         Subscription_parameters=["'catchupNotificationsEnabled': True",
"'newsNotificationsEnabled': True", "'autoDownloadsEnabled': False"])])
```

Split this array into three columns, by simple indexing :

```
df = df.select("Subscription_id", 
      F.col("Subscription_parameters")[0].alias("catchupNotificationsEnabled"),
      F.col("Subscription_parameters")[1].alias("newsNotificationsEnabled"),
      F.col("Subscription_parameters")[2].alias("autoDownloadsEnabled"))
```

Now your DataFrame is properly split, each new column contains a string such as e.g. "'catchupNotificationsEnabled': True" :

```
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|Subscription_id|catchupNotificationsEnabled|newsNotificationsEnabled|autoDownloadsEnabled|
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|           5516|       'catchupNotificat...|    'newsNotification...|'autoDownloadsEna...|
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

Then I suggest to update column values by checking if it contains "True" or not

```
df = df.withColumn('catchupNotificationsEnabled',
                  F.when(F.col("catchupNotificationsEnabled").contains("True"), True).otherwise(False))\
        .withColumn('newsNotificationsEnabled',
                   F.when(F.col("newsNotificationsEnabled").contains("True"), True).otherwise(False))\
        .withColumn('autoDownloadsEnabled',
                   F.when(F.col("autoDownloadsEnabled").contains("True"), True).otherwise(False))
```

The resulting DataFrame is as expected

```
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|Subscription_id|catchupNotificationsEnabled|newsNotificationsEnabled|autoDownloadsEnabled|
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|           5516|                       true|                    true|               false|
+---------------+---------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

PS: if the column is not of ArrayType() you might have to modify this code a little bit.[See this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below

```
>>> df.show()
+---------------+-----------------------+
|Subscription_id|Subscription_parameters|
+---------------+-----------------------+
|           5516|   ["'catchupNotific...|
+---------------+-----------------------+

>>> 
>>> df1 = df.select('Subscription_id')
>>> 
>>> data = df.select('Subscription_parameters').rdd.map(list).collect()
>>> data = [i[0][1:-1].split(',') for i in data]
>>> data = {i.split(':')[0][2:-1]:i.split(':')[1].strip()[:-1] for i in data[0]}
>>> 
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([data]))
>>> 
>>> df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
>>> 
>>> df3.show()
+---------------+--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
|Subscription_id|autoDownloadsEnabled|catchupNotificationsEnabled|newsNotificationsEnabled|
+---------------+--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
|           5516|               False|                       True|                    True|
+---------------+--------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Both the solutions work for me!