# Adding dictionary keys as column name and dictionary value as the constant value of that column in Pyspark df

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dictionary `x = {'colA': 20, 'colB': 30}` and a pyspark df.

```
ID Value
1  ABC
1  BCD
1  AKB
2  CAB
2  AIK
3  KIB
```

I want to create df1 using x as follows:

```
ID Value colA colB
1  ABC    20.0  30.0
1  BCD    20.0  30.0
1  AKB    20.0  30.0
2  CAB    20.0  30.0
...
```

Any idea how to do it Pyspark.
I know I can create a constant column like this,

```
df1 = df.withColumn('colA', lit(20.0))
df1 = df1.withColumn('colB', lit(30.0))
```

But not sure about the dynamic process to do it from dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the dictionary as below

```
df1 = df  
for key in x:
    df1 = df1.withColumn(key, lit(x[key]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to apply all the keys together to create all the columns at once without going through the loop?

Comment: even if you apply it in a loop spark will execute it only once since it's a lazy evaluation... you don't need worry about performance.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I also got to this solution but i thought it was inefficient. That's why asked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to *hide* the loop, but the execution will be the same. For instance, you can use `select`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df2 = df.select("*", *[lit(val).alias(key) for key, val in x.items()])
df2.show()
#+---+-----+----+----+
#| ID|Value|colB|colA|
#+---+-----+----+----+
#|  1|  ABC|  30|  20|
#|  1|  BCD|  30|  20|
#|  1|  AKB|  30|  20|
#|  2|  CAB|  30|  20|
#|  2|  AIK|  30|  20|
#|  3|  KIB|  30|  20|
#+---+-----+----+----+
```

Or `functools.reduce` and `withColumn`:

```python
from functools import reduce
df3 = reduce(lambda df, key: df.withColumn(key, lit(x[key])), x, df)
df3.show()
# Same as above
```

Or [`pyspark.sql.functions.struct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) with [`select()` and the `"*"` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45791853/5858851):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
df4 = df.withColumn('x', struct([lit(val).alias(key) for key, val in x.items()]))\
    .select("ID", "Value", "x.*")
df4.show()
#Same as above
```

But if you look at the execution plan of these methods, you'll see that they're exactly the same:

```python
df2.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ID#44L, Value#45, 30 AS colB#151, 20 AS colA#152]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[ID#44L,Value#45]

df3.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ID#44L, Value#45, 30 AS colB#102, 20 AS colA#107]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[ID#44L,Value#45]

df4.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ID#44L, Value#45, 30 AS colB#120, 20 AS colA#121]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[ID#44L,Value#45]
```

Further if you compare the loop method in @anil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609408/5858851):

```python
df1 = df  
for key in x:
    df1 = df1.withColumn(key, lit(x[key]))
df1.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ID#44L, Value#45, 30 AS colB#127, 20 AS colA#132]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[ID#44L,Value#45]
```

You'll see that this is the same as well.

Comment: I have a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318004/pyspark-dealing-w-dict-with-no-values @pault