# PySpark: Expand the json to new columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have data of the following kind:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|         id|      point|                         data                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        dfb|          6|[{"key1":"124", "key2": "345"},{"key3":"324", "key1":"wfe"}] |
|        bgd|          7|[{"key3":"324", "key1":"wfe"},{"key1":"777", "key2":"888"}]  |
|        34d|          6|[{"key1":"111", "key4": "788", "key2":"dfef}]                |
```

and I want to convert it to

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|         id|      point|                         key1                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        dfb|          6|    124                                        |     
|        bgd|          7|    777                                        |
|        34d|          6|    111                                        |
```

There exist a lists of JSONs and they may share common keys but I want to extract value of key1 from the json which also has key2.

This can be easily achieved in python.

In pyspark I have seen solutions([How to split a list to multiple columns in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)) which are based on fixed schema, but how can I achieve this without a fixed schema as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `higher_order_functions` (spark 2.4+) involving `filter` with `transform`can be:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),StringType()))

(df.withColumn("data",F.from_json(F.col("data"),schema))
   .withColumn("Key1",F.expr('''transform(filter(data,x-> 
   array_contains(map_keys(x),"key2")),y->y["key1"])''')[0])).show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+--------------------+----+
| id|point|                data|Key1|
+---+-----+--------------------+----+
|dfb|    6|[[key1 -> 124, ke...| 124|
|bgd|    7|[[key3 -> 324, ke...| 777|
|34d|    6|[[key1 -> 111, ke...| 111|
+---+-----+--------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

```
df.show()
+---+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id |point|data                                                     |
+---+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|dfb|6    |[{"key1":"124","key2":"345"},{"key3":"324","key1":"wfe"}]|
|bgd|7    |[{"key3":"324","key1":"wfe"},{"key1":"777","key2":"888"}]|
|34d|6    |[{"key1":"111","key4":"788","key2":"dfef"}]              |
+---+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
```

```
df.withColumn("data",F.explode(F.from_json(F.col("data"),schema))).withColumn("data",F.when(F.col("data")["key1"].cast("long").isNotNull(),F.col("data")["key1"])).filter(F.col("data").isNotNull()).show()

+---+-----+----+
| id|point|data|
+---+-----+----+
|dfb|    6| 124|
|bgd|    7| 777|
|34d|    6| 111|
+---+-----+----+
```