# Break a dictionary out of a StringType column in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I have a spark table that I want to read in python (I'm using python 3 in databricks)  In effect the structure is below.  The log data is stored in a single string column but is a dictionary.

How do I break out the dictionary items to read them.

```
dfstates = spark.createDataFrame([[{"EVENT_ID":"123829:0","EVENT_TS":"2020-06-22T10:16:01.000+0000","RECORD_INDEX":0},
                                   {"EVENT_ID":"123829:1","EVENT_TS":"2020-06-22T10:16:01.000+0000","RECORD_INDEX":1},
                                   {"EVENT_ID":"123828:0","EVENT_TS":"2020-06-20T21:17:39.000+0000","RECORD_INDEX":0}],
                                   ['texas','24','01/04/2019'],
                                   ['colorado','13','01/07/2019'],
                                   ['maine','14','']]).toDF('LogData','State','Orders','OrdDate')
```

What I want to do is read the spark table into a dataframe, find the max event timestamp, find the rows with that timestamp then count and read just those rows into a new dataframe with the data columns and from the log data, add columns for event id (without the record index), event date and record index.

Downstream I'll be validating the data, converting from StringType to appropriate data type and filling in missing or invalid values as appropriate.  All along I'll be asserting that row counts = original row counts.

The only thing I'm stuck on though is how to read this log data column and change it to something I can work with.  Something in spark like pandas.series()?

Comment: can you include the schema of your dataframe?

Comment: For the example, the eventual structure will be. StructType[(
      StructField('State',StringType(),True),
      StructField('Orders',IntegerType(), True),
      StructField('OrdDate',DateType(), True),
      StructField('Event_Id',StringType(),True),
      StructFiled('EventDate',DateType(), True),
      StructField('RecordId', StringType(), True)
)]

Comment: The current structure is all StringType, Essentially due to security issues, sysops have a generic solution which ingests log files via S3 and lands them all as spark tables, all columns as strings.  Each group only sees the databases where their own log tables are mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your single struct type column into multiple columns using `dfstates.select('Logdata.*)` Refer this answer : [How to split a list to multiple columns in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789489/how-to-split-a-list-to-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)
Once you have seperate columns, then you can do standard pyspark operations like filtering

Comment: Excellent, that has done it.  It never occurred to me but it recognises the string column as a dictionary so I can do - dfnew = dfstates.select(dfstates.logdata['EVENT_ID'], dfstates.logdata['EVENT_TS'], dfstates.logdata[RECORD_INDEX]).  Just what I need, thank you very much.